# How do I replace an uninstalled system application

Tags: applications, system

I mistakenly uninstalled my Download Manager 4.4.4 in my Samsung Galaxy Grand prime G530H. A system application. I tried replacing it with a Download Manager 2.3.5. I did that by using a file explorer to place the 2.3.5 in the system folder. Then I rebooted the phone. It didn't work. The phone doesn't recognize the 2.3.5. Looking through the file explorer I can see the  Download Manager 2.3.5 is still in the system/app folder and I tried deleting it but it won't delete.
I need help on how to get the original Download Manager 4.4.4.

Comment: Can you just push a custom ROM to your phone and be done with it?

Comment: Mike? Can I call you Mike? what's a custom ROM? If you have one can you send to me?

Comment: Resetting the device might bring back the app.

Comment: @okeke I have added an answer that will hopefully help :)

Comment: Custom ROMs are like different OS. They are based off of android (as android is open source). You don't need Michael Nancarrow to send you a ROM, you can search one up (perhaps cyanogenmod for it's fame), find build, and flash. But that might not be necessary

Answer (score 0):

Okeke,

Refer to `MANI's` answer regarding resetting the device, this *may* assist you, but as far as I am aware a reset does not touch where the applications are actually stored.

**What is a ROM?**

Read Only Memory. Essentially just a new firmware/software for your Android Phone. For a more detailed explanation and information on a ROM look on this [website](http://droidlessons.com/what-are-roms-for-android/). 
If unsure if you should do this process, read on How To Geek about the "[Top 5 Reasons to install a Custom ROM](http://www.howtogeek.com/173206/5-reasons-to-install-a-custom-android-rom-and-why-you-might-not-want-to/?PageSpeed=noscript)"

**Process for your Phone**

Here is [an example of how to install a custom ROM on your phone](http://www.droidviews.com/install-android-5-0-2-lollipop-firmware-on-galaxy-grand-prime-sm-g530h/) (including Drivers, links to ROM etc.)

Here is the [Xda Forum for your phone](http://forum.xda-developers.com/grand-prime). Covers troubleshooting, ROMS etc. I would suggest you look here also.

**Other Resources**

Refer to [this question on SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/45233/what-if-you-accidentally-deleted-some-important-apps-and-cant-install-them-back) that provides a detailed answer (thanks @Izzy)

Hope this helps you. Undoubtedly a Factory Reset could assist, but I am not 100%. The steps for a Factory Reset on your device are located [here](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/samsung/samsung-g530h-galaxy-grand-prime/).

Regards

*Mike*

Comment: Thank you Mani. Mike. I just signed up at the xda forum. I have requested for help. Just hope someone can help

Comment: @okeke Let me know how this goes.